# Should I subclass JFrame/JPanel or not?

Tags: java, swing

I was used to subclassing the window-classes in other programming environment, but in the java tutorials I usually see something like

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

p.add(aComponent);
p.add(anotherComponent);
```

So what are the conventions in Java regarding subclassing top-container classes?

Comment: This question is similar to should I use anonymous Classes or should I name them -> there is no right or wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same principle as you would for all java classes. If you are modifying or extending the behaviour or functionality, then by all means, extend `JPanel` or `JFrame`. The trick is to think carefully and decide if you really are adding anything. In *most* cases when I see people extending `JFrame` it is unnecessary and wrong;

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Why bother extending `JFrame`? You haven't added anything! Composition is a much better option.

Extending `JPanel` is a little different. JPanel is a fairly abstract idea, its just a generic container for other components. IMHO it is valid to subclass `JPanel` to create a more concrete panel, and then use that in your application. It promotes OOP and encapsulation.

For example, say your GUI had 2 main display areas; one with some buttons/controls/inputs and another which displayed output (eg in a text area). It is perfectly acceptable to subclass `JPanel` to create a ControlPanel that contains the buttons/controls/inputs. This moves all the code into a nice neat module, cleaning up your class that contains and handles the main `JFrame`.

Comment: Often, when people have a main application class with data attributes and business logic etc, you see them extending JFrame purely in order to give their app a GUI. IMO this is wrong, because it's not an *is-a*, it's a *has-a*! As you said, composition the correct approach. However, if you do *need* to extend JFrame/JPanel to **add some UI-related functionality to it**, don't use this an excuse to put everything in one class. You should give your application class an instance of your extended JFrame, and not start storing business logic/data in what should be a purely UI class. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule for this, it depends how you think about your Object. You may have a JPanel which has a specific layout and bahavior, so its e.g. a VideoViewerPanel. But even this VideoViewerPanel may contain a JPanel which is only there to arrange some Buttons so you do not expicitly name it and just use it as JPanel.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the Liskov substitution principle,
you should look into it.

[Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

[Liskov substitution principle: Applied example](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html)

Answer (score 2):

A well-known and good practice is to avoid subclassing top-level containers (`JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JInternalFrame`).

Regarding `JPanel`, several practices are in use:

- subclass it for every **view** (then add
  all components inside the subclass
  constructor)
- create a **ViewBuilder** (for each kind
  of **view**) that dynamically adds
  components to a "standard" `JPanel`

I generally use the first option, which seems more logical to me, but I also sometimes use the second way, with some level of adaptation: my view builder actually creates and stores (as fields) all components but adds them to an existing panel (passed as an argument).

For example, I use that in order to reuse sets of components: e.g. I have an `AddressView` class that works like that and I add it twice to a `ContactView` that subclasses `JPanel`, once for *home address*, once for *office address*.

One may say that I could also subclass `JPanel` for `AddressView` and then add 2 instances to my `ContactView` panel. The reason I don't do that is because Swing `LayoutManager`s don't support alignment of components across different panels, thus the resulting ContactView panel is not visually pleasing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My general rule of thumb: *Before using inheritance, consider if composition makes more sense.*

Reason: *Subclassing usually means more complexity and connectedness, i.e. harder to change, maintain, and scale without making mistakes.*

A much more complete and concrete [answer from Tim Boudreau](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?forumID=61&threadID=16487#91822172) of Sun:

> Common problems to the use of inheritance as I see it are:
>
> - *Innocent acts can have unexpected results* - The classic example of this is calls to overridable methods from the superclass
>     constructor, before the subclasses instance fields have been
>     initialized. In a perfect world, nobody would ever do that. This is
>     not a perfect world.
> - *It offers perverse temptations for subclassers to make assumptions about order of method calls and such* - such assumptions tend not to
>     be stable if the superclass may evolve over time. See also [my toaster
>     and coffee pot analogy](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16036&messageID=91819530#91819530).
> - *Classes get heavier* - you don't necessarily know what work your superclass is doing in its constructor, or how much memory it's going
>     to use. So constructing some innocent would-be lightweight object can
>     be far more expensive than you think, and this may change over time if
>     the superclass evolves
> - *It encourages an explosion of subclasses*. Classloading costs time, more classes costs memory. This may be a non-issue until you're
>     dealing with an app on the scale of NetBeans, but there, we had real
>     issues with, for example, menus being slow because the first display
>     of a menu triggered massive class loading. We fixed this by moving to
>     more declarative syntax and other techniques, but that cost time to
>     fix as well.
> - *It makes it harder to change things later* - if you've made a class public, swapping the superclass is going to break subclasses -
>     it's a choice which, once you've made the code public, you're married
>     to. So if you're not altering the real functionality to your
>     superclass, you get much more freedom to change things later if you
>     use, rather than extend the thing you need. Take, for example,
>     subclassing JPanel - this is usually wrong; and if the subclass is
>     public somewhere, you never get a chance to revisit that decision. If
>     it's accessed as JComponent getThePanel() , you can still do it (hint:
>     expose models for the components within as your API).
> - *Object hierarchies don't scale (or making them scale later is much harder than planning ahead)* - this is the classic "too many layers"
>     problem. I'll go into this below, and how the AskTheOracle pattern can
>     solve it (though it may offend OOP purists).
>
> ...
>
> My take on what to do, if you do allow for inheritance, which you may
>   take with a grain of salt is:
>
> - Expose no fields, ever, except constants
> - Methods shall be either abstract or final
> - Call no methods from the superclass constructor
>
> ...
>
> all of this applies less to small projects than large ones, and less
>   to private classes than public ones