# Java Multidemensional Array Loop that inputs data with Button Action

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jbutton

Questions I am pulling my hair out over.

1. How do I get the array to add data to current index, then increment to the next index to add changed JTextField data for the next button press. currently I'm overwriting the same index.

I have tried to figure out actionlisteners for the button "Submit" that uses a counter with nesting of the loop. played with ideas from question 23331198 and 3010840 and 17829577 many others as a reference but didn't really get it to far. Most searches pull up info on managing buttons with arrays and creating button arrays so I assume I'm not using the correct wording to search with. I have read a few places that an MD array is not the best option to use.

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class GUIandLogicTest extends JFrame
    {
    // Variable Decloration
    private static JFrame mainFrame;
    private static JPanel mainPanel;
    private static JTextField fieldOne;
    private static JTextField fieldTwo;
    private static JTextArea textArea;
    private static JLabel textFieldOneLabel;
    private static JLabel textFieldTwoLabel;

    double[][] tutArray = new double[10][2];

    // int i =0 ;

    // Set GUI method
    private void gui()

    {
        // constructs GUI
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        textFieldOneLabel = new JLabel("number 1");
        mainPanel.add(textFieldOneLabel);
        fieldOne = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(fieldOne);

        textFieldTwoLabel = new JLabel("number 2");
        mainPanel.add(textFieldTwoLabel);
        fieldTwo = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(fieldTwo);
        textArea = new JTextArea(50, 50);

        mainPanel.add(textArea);

        JButton Exit = new JButton("Quit");// Quits program
        mainPanel.add(Exit);
        Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JButton submit = new JButton("Enter");
        // Reads jfields and set varibles to be submitted to array
        mainPanel.add(submit);

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {

                double txtField1 = Double
                        .parseDouble(fieldOne.getText().trim());
                double txtField2 = Double
                        .parseDouble(fieldTwo.getText().trim());

                if (txtField1 < 0)
                {

                }

                if (txtField2 < 0)
                {

                }

                int arrayIndex = 0;
                tutArray[arrayIndex][0] = txtField1;
                tutArray[arrayIndex][1] = txtField2;
                arrayIndex++;

                for (int i = 0; i < tutArray.length; i++)
                {

                    textArea.append("Number1: " + tutArray[i][0] + " Number2: "
                            + tutArray[i][1]);
                    textArea.append("\n");
                    textArea.append(String.valueOf(arrayIndex++));
                    textArea.append("\n");
                    // textArea.append(String.valueOf(arrayIndex++));

                }
            }

        });

        JButton report = new JButton();
        // will be used to pull data out of array with formatting and math
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        GUIandLogicTest GUIandLogic = new GUIandLogicTest();
        GUIandLogic.start();

    }

    public void start()
    {
        gui();
    }
    }
```

This is what I was looking for thanks for the help!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIandLogicTest extends JFrame
{
// Variable Decloration
private static JFrame mainFrame;
private static JPanel mainPanel;
private static JTextField fieldOne;
private static JTextField fieldTwo;
private static JTextArea textArea;
private static JLabel textFieldOneLabel;
private static JLabel textFieldTwoLabel;

double[][] tutArray = new double[10][2];
 int arrayIndex = 0;
// int i =0 ;

// Set GUI method
private void gui()

{
    // constructs GUI
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setSize(800, 800);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    textFieldOneLabel = new JLabel("number 1");
    mainPanel.add(textFieldOneLabel);
    fieldOne = new JTextField(10);
    mainPanel.add(fieldOne);

    textFieldTwoLabel = new JLabel("number 2");
    mainPanel.add(textFieldTwoLabel);
    fieldTwo = new JTextField(10);
    mainPanel.add(fieldTwo);
    textArea = new JTextArea(50, 50);

    mainPanel.add(textArea);

    JButton Exit = new JButton("Quit");// Quits program
    mainPanel.add(Exit);
    Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    JButton submit = new JButton("Enter");
    // Reads jfields and set varibles to be submitted to array
    mainPanel.add(submit);

    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {

            double txtField1 = Double
                    .parseDouble(fieldOne.getText().trim());
            double txtField2 = Double
                    .parseDouble(fieldTwo.getText().trim());
textArea.setText("");
            if (txtField1 < 0)
            {

            }

            if (txtField2 < 0)
            {

            }


            tutArray[arrayIndex][0] = txtField1;
            tutArray[arrayIndex][1] = txtField2;
            arrayIndex++;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayIndex; i++)
            {

                textArea.append("Number1: " + tutArray[i][0] + " Number2: "
                        + tutArray[i][1]);
               // textArea.append("\n");
                //textArea.append(String.valueOf(arrayIndex++));
                textArea.append("\n");
                // textArea.append(String.valueOf(arrayIndex++));

            }
        }

    });

    JButton report = new JButton();
    // will be used to pull data out of array with formatting and math
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    GUIandLogicTest GUIandLogic = new GUIandLogicTest();
    GUIandLogic.start();

}

public void start()
{
    gui();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the index as a field in your main object:

```
protected int index;
```

in your actionPerformed you increase index:

```
index++;
```

NOTE:

But why do you extend from JFrame AND use the field mainFrame?

you can use

```
this.setSize(800,800);
this.add(mainPanel);
```

Please declare (because of extends JFrame):

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Please start the name of an object with a lower case letter:

```
JButton exit = new JButton("Quit");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought i was increasing the index"arrayIndex++" moved variable deceleration as suggested.extends JFrame I have had added and removed it a few times depending on what the current reading material is.I have not noticed any difference but then again at this point. I tried the "this" tag in the past as the book said to but it gives a code error not sure why it is on my list of things to figure out after I get the loop and array working.Again thank you for the feed back I lean more from being torn apart then from just reading.

Comment: @PCGIZMO
Sorry, i named arrayIndex -> index and moved it as an protected field into the main class.
look here for extends jframe : 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895282/should-i-subclass-jframe-jpanel-or-not)

Comment: the "this"error?  cannot find symbol.  Symbol:method setSize(int,int)

Comment: `import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class MyFrame extends JFrame
    {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public MyFrame()
 {
  this.setSize(200, 200);
  this.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  new MyFrame();
 }

    }
` Sorry, i cant find any error. This works perfect on my conputer... .