# Eclipse program JPanel wont run

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, runtime-error

I'm not sure why but when I try to run this the only thing that shows is the last program I ran, I even added the serialVersionUID and it still wont show. Anyone have an i dea on why, maybe some setup problem on my eclipse or coomputer?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Shapes extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int choice;

    public Shapes(int userChoice) {
        choice = userChoice;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; 1 < 10; i++) {
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                g.drawRect(10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10);
            case 2:
                g.drawOval(10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, you don´t have any `main`, so how should this run from this class?

Comment: On another note, you need to break each case statement, at the moment you're going to run into unexpected problems if you don't have a `break;` after `case 1:`'s code

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Your panel has no preferred size; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37450393/230513).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have no entry-point to your program. You can't just expect a program in Java, or basically any other compiled language to run without an entry point.

Inside your class, you need to have the following for the program to begin:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Entry-point began. Put code in here.
}
```

Secondly, it is not a good practise (correct me if I'm wrong) to extend any of the `JComponent` derivatives. Without explaining again, a good reason can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895282/should-i-subclass-jframe-jpanel-or-not):

**Excerpt:**

> - It makes it harder to change things later - if you've made a class public, swapping the superclass is going to break subclasses - it's a choice which, once you've made the code public, you're married to. So if you're not altering the real functionality to your superclass, you get much more freedom to change things later if you use, rather than extend the thing you need. Take, for example, subclassing JPanel - this is usually wrong; and if the subclass is public somewhere, you never get a chance to revisit that decision. If it's accessed as JComponent getThePanel() , you can still do it (hint: expose models for the components within as your API). **This especially applies because your class is a `Shape`. So when `Shape` extends JPanel, every single shape will.**
> - Object hierarchies don't scale (or making them scale later is much harder than planning ahead) - this is the classic "too many layers" problem. I'll go into this below, and how the AskTheOracle pattern can solve it (though it may offend OOP purists).

Especially since you are extending `JPanel`, and aren't even initialising a `JFrame` to begin with. Before starting out with Swing applications in Java, you should read the JavaDoc and Oracles examples beforehand...

JavaDoc: [**JFrame**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) / [**JPanel**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)
Example: [How to make Frames.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

So, revising on what I have said, a ***basic*** Swing class would look as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Shapes {

    public Shapes() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel window = new JPanel();

        frame.setSize(600, 400); // Width: 600, Height: 400.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(window);

        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Perform graphics drawing.

        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shapes();
    }

}
```